# Find exact strings while looping through a range using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that goes through a table. When it finds the word "Reporting" in column C and "OSI" in column B, it creates a range called "OSIRep" going from column D-E-F for every row where the criteria in column B and C are true.

```
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")


'Reporting and OSI

Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rngArray = featuresRng
ReDim NewArr(1 To 1)
y = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
    If rngArray(i, 2) = "Reporting" And rngArray(i, 1) = "OSI" Then
        ReDim Preserve NewArr(1 To y)
        NewArr(y) = featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, 2).Address
        y = y + 1

    End If
Next i

sRng = Join(NewArr, Application.DecimalSeparator)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OSIRep", sht.Range(sRng)
```

However, I have two problems with this:
1- When I change the word to "Security" and "OSI" to create a range "OSISec", I get an error and I don't know why. The error is 'Run-Time error 1004 - Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed' and this occurs on sht.Range(sRng)

The range it is searching through is no different and the name I am trying to create doesn't already exist. Any ideas?

2- When I change the strings to "Reporting" and "Search and Filter", the code creates a range where any cells containing the words "Search" or "and" or "Filter" are included in the range. How do I search for the EXACT string? I believe it uses Find and xlwhole? I am not sure how to use this though?

I have tried taking an protections of the worksheet, unlocking cells and exploring the error code, all to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any help or insight you can provide! I appreciate I am a complete beginner, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What line you are getting the error ?

Comment: HI @FAB, it is on this line: 
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add "OSIRep", sht.Range(sRng)

I think it is in the sht.Range(sRng)...?

Comment: I don't understand, `If rngArray(i, 1) =  "Search and Filter"` will return `False` if the element contains only "and". You would need to explicitly let the code know to look for only part of the string, that is not a standard setting

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on that line, what you get if you do `?sRng.Address` in immediate window?

Comment: For me your code is working. I think you have some hidden names making  problems. You can Loop through also hidden names with: 
   For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
       Debug.Print nm.Name
    Next nm

Comment: I get the following:
?sRng.Address$D$3:$F$8
$D$11:$F$17
$D$18:$F$20
$D$33:$F$33
$D$39:$F$41
$D$42:$F$54
$D$66:$F$83,$D$128:$F$128
$D$84:$F$91,$D$174:$F$174
$D$92:$F$94,$D$173:$F$173
$D$95:$F$105,$D$175:$F$175
$D$95:$F$105,$D$175:$F$175

but the only range it should in fact refer to is D61:F64, I believe it is picking up other cells where OSI exists and not Security...

Comment: However, still doesn't explain why I get the application error...

Comment: @cekar yes good idea - I saw some names that I didn't recognize and have deleted them. However, this has made no difference to my code not working :\

Comment: @TimStack yes that is what I thought... I am unsure why the code isn't working if my string contains more than one word and why, when it does work, it would return all cells with strings contains partial details..

Comment: does it make any difference if you say rngArray(i, 2).Value and rngArray(i, 1).Value?

Comment: @JeremyKahan good idea, but I get a 424 run time error on that line saying Object Required if I add in 'Value'

Comment: Oh, okay. You could pull out StrCompare, but I doubt that would do anything except uglify the code. I suspect that the 424 error would go away if you said Set rngArray=featuresRng, but that might create other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand the problem but maybe there are some issues with your files. When I use this test setup:

[image]

With this code:

```
Sub SOCode()
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Features")

Set featuresRng = sht.Range(sht.Range("B1"), sht.Range("C" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
rngArray = featuresRng

ReDim NewArr(1 To 1)
y = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(rngArray)
    If rngArray(i, 2) = sht.Range("F2") And rngArray(i, 1) = sht.Range("F1") Then
        ReDim Preserve NewArr(1 To y)
        NewArr(y) = featuresRng.Rows(i).Resize(1, 3).Offset(0, 2).Address
        y = y + 1

    End If
Next i

'delete all named ranges first
Dim nm As Name
For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    nm.Delete
Next nm

sRng = Join(NewArr, Application.DecimalSeparator)
ThisWorkbook.Names.Add sht.Range("F3").Value, sht.Range(sRng)

'delete output of named ranges from last test
Range("H2:H1000").ClearContents

'paste named ranges in col "H"
i = 2
For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    Cells(i, 8).Value = nm.Name
    i = i + 1
Next nm
End Sub
```

All possible strings you mentioned are working on my site.

[image]
I would create a fresh new file and test it again. I changed your code only in reading the possible strings from column F (OSI in F1, e.g. reporting =F2, rangeName=F3)  and paste finally all created names to column H just for debugging. Remember that I get error when there isn't a combination found, as then creation of named range with an empty string in "sRng" results in an error of course.

Comment: Hi @cekar, thanks so much for your solution and suggestions. However, despite creating the file fresh again, deleting all named ranges and then running the code, I get the same issue... 
The combination that I am searching for does exist, so in theory there should be no error..

Any other ideas why this may be?

Comment: @PKen: have you set the spreadsheet as I did and pasted my Code? What errors do you receive and where?

Comment: Hi @cekar, I get errors on both the 
sRng = Join(NewArr, Application.DecimalSeparator)

and 

ThisWorkbook.Names.Add sht.Range("F3").Value, sht.Range(sRng) lines

Comment: Hi PKen, unfortunately I don't know what we can test now as I cannot reproduce your error. As I said with the Code above I can use every kind of string combination to create named ranges of. I thought that you might have a file corruption therefore I asked for creating a complete new and empty file. But you said that it is still not possible, so I have no idea at the moment.